# Large number of open connections to database crashes the application

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, sap-ase

In my web service, i connect to Sybase database.

I have list of Doctors and each doctor can be associated with number of Hospitals. I need to update a few details on every Hospital with which a Doctor is working.

For every doctor a new connection to database is opened.For every Doctor in a list, I first get the list of Hospitals in the DbReader and i do operations on each Hospital in the reader. Once all the records in the DbReader are processed, I close the reader along with the connection. (This is because i pass `System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection` to the `ExecuteReader()` method of the `Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseCommand` class)

Now, if the number of doctors are beyond some limit, I get errors since the number of connections which are open become very large.

**Which different approach can i use in this scenario to get rid of the error? How to know the number of open connections from client side?**

One of the thing i can do is - don't open a new connection until previous connection is closed. But this approach is not that good (I think) because, though multiple connections are allowed, i'll be having one connection at a time.

Comment: you should show your code, the place where you are looping on all doctors and how you use your ExecuteReader.

Comment: @David Piras: Code is quite large and spread across multiple methods. I have a method which returns the Reader object which contains the list/records of Hospitals in it. I call this method from some other method. When I get the Reader object and if it has records, I process each record and in 'finally' block i close the reader (which in turn closes the connection.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not using connection pooling? or implement a singleton connectionmanager which provides new connections as long as the limit is not reached.

Besides are you sure you need Multiconnection in this case? it sounds like you have to run the same process for each Doctor. So you can do it in a loop, guess one connection will be enough for that.

Comment: Single connection will not do because the client code is web service and there are many web methods which will call this particular piece of code.

Comment: OPening multiple connections is not helping you in anyway from that viewpoint because the connections opened on one web service call, i.e thread are not available for use by a different web service call (Different thread.)  You should be opening one connection doing all the work on it and then closing it.

Comment: @Sisyphus: You and @O.D are right. I dont need multiple connection. I did changes to use single connection and it solved my problem.